# How to create a polymorphic relationship in Laravel when a relationship "may" not exist?

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have a posts table and a post may have one media. It can be a video or a gallery. This is easy, what I did was set up a polymorphic relationship and it worked.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| posts                                                    |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| id   | title           | content | media_id | media_type |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 1    | Some Awesome... | Rea...  | 10       | Video      |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 2    | Cool Photos...  | See...  | 12       | Gallery    |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 3    | Watch The...    | See...  | 22       | Video      |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
```

The problem is some post does not have a media and a polymorphic relationship joins a record to the model specified in its type field.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| posts                                                    |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| id   | title           | content | media_id | media_type |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 1    | Some Awesome... | Rea...  | 10       | Video      |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 2    | Cool Photos...  | See...  | 12       | Gallery    |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 3    | Watch The...    | See...  | 22       | Video      |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 4    | Top 10 Games... | Play... | 0        | ?          |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 5    | Do You Want...  | Buil... | 0        | ?          |
+------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
```

Setting up the media_type as empty would cause an error because it would search for an empty string class. What would be the best way to setup this kind of relationship? Should I just join them to some fake table (please no.)? Or is there a proper way of dealing with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for your problem is dividing posts table and polymorphic relation table. For example, Your posts table contains only post information and relation table contain post_id and relation info so that you don't need to concern whether media is exist or not. Like this,

```
+----------------------------------|
| posts                            |
+------+-----------------+---------|
| id   | title           | content |
+------+-----------------+---------|
| 1    | Some Awesome... | Rea...  |
+------+-----------------+---------|
| 2    | Cool Photos...  | See...  |
+------+-----------------+---------|
| 3    | Watch The...    | See...  |
+------+-----------------+---------|

+----------------------------------------+
| media                                  |
+------+---------+----------+------------|
| id   | post_id | media_id | media_type |
+------+---------+----------+------------|
| 1    | 1       | 10       | Video      |
+------+---------+----------+------------|
| 2    | 2       | 12       | Gallery    |
+------+---------+----------+------------|
| 3    | 3       | 22       | Video      |
+------+---------+----------+------------|
```

In Media model

```
public function medias()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In Post model, it will be one-to-one or one-to-many relation (whatever you like) with Media model.

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Media');
}

OR

public function media()
{
   return $this->hasOne('Media');
}
```

In Video, Gallery model, They have polymorphic relationship with Media model.

```
public function media()
{
return $this->morphMany('Media', 'medias');
}
```